# SilverStripe 4 GraphQL and GraphiQL UI not working even the procedures were followed properly from the documentation

Tags: graphql, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm using SilverStripe 4 and applied a plug-in using `composer require silverstripe/graphql`.

After following the instructions from the document of `silverstripe/graphql` from this source https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-graphql, I can't seem to access the `GraphiQL` of the `GraphQL` through this url `localhost/silverstripe/dev/graphiql` (silverstripe is the name of my folder in htdocs, graphiql is the UI counter part that will help me to perform queries for `GraphQL`)

GraphQL sample output:

[image: Output for GraphiQL]

**Using Postman:**

[image: POST method using Postman]

GraphiQL sample output:

[image: GraphiQL route not working]

My namepace is `SS\GraphQL`

[image: File Directory]

[image: Sample Code]

Also applied this into my `routes.yml` file:

[image: routes.yml]

I have these inside a `GraphQL` folder inside the `_config`

[image: GraphQL]

`membertypecreator.yml`:

[image]

`readmemberquerycreator.yml`:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here? I was able to reproduce the steps and codes from the documentation
Kindly requesting for your help please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK FINALLY, was able to answer my query, by installing `composer require --dev silverstripe/graphql-devtools`, I was able to go to `localhost/silverstripe/dev/graphiql` and was able to open this UI:

[image: GraphiQL]